# Quickbooks integration failing with new Office 2013

Tags: windows-7-x64, quickbooks, office-2013, qbfc

having trouble with getting my new Windows 7 laptop with 64 bit Office 2013, to integrate with Quickbooks 2013 from MSAccess 2013, using QBFC 11.   Previous version that worked was Windows XP 32 bit, Access 2010 and QB 2013, with same QBFC11.

Using the new install, integration code fails immediately with "error 429 Active X component can't create object" when i try to create a session requestmsgset.  I have searched a bunch to find non-specific answers which don't seem to apply or give me clues, does anyone have any idea how to fix this for Quickbooks?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When installing Office 365 (the sister product to Office 2013), you are given the option to install 32-bit or 64-bit.  But it recommends you use 32-bit, saying that most software is still operating with only 32-bit hooks and that a 64-bit version of Office will not work properly.  I don't *know* that this is your difficulty, but that's what I would look at first.